# Mailgun Forwarded Mail Attachment Format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailgun

I'm trying to receive and parse a forwarded mail using Mailgun Routes. This mail has attachments, so I read the documentation for attachments and also sent a test POST to bin.mailgun - trying to see what the format is. Here's a screenshot -

[image]

According to this, `attachment-1` is a JSON object, while `attachment-2` is a string. In Rails, the `attachment-1` is automatically parsed and presented as a `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile`.

So what is the correct format? Can it be both an `UploadedFile` object or a string at any time? What should I parse for?

Comment: you hare using a gem?

Comment: Not using any gem.

Comment: You configure a Mailgun Route to forward a email to your Rails system and then process the email and get this result? What you get if you send  the email direct to your system with the same files attached? I think both  are correct format like when you get a txt attached file in some email server you can see embeded in the content.

Comment: That's what confuses me, how can both be the correct format? If it's a text file, then it should mention the metadata for it right? It shouldn't just send a string in place of a File object.

Comment: I pushed it to production with my fingers crossed and it seems no text string is ever passed, the proper File object is always sent. Not sure why the documentation/sample in the mailgun site was incorrect, closing this.

Comment: maybe you can chek the attach class like  `attach1.class == Hash` and `attach1 == String` and process acording the class